# Mostrar el valor de matricula en un textfield y ComboBox dependientes (anidados)

Tags: java, netbeans

necesito ayuda es sobre comboBox dependientes, trata sobre que en el primer comboBox se debe mostrar una lista de universidades y dependiendo de cual se elija  en el segundo se muestren sus sedes, hasta ahí tengo el código, pero aparte de eso al seleccionar la sede se debe mostrar en un text filed el precio de la matricula, pero no se como seguir con el codigo.

```
public String[] getSedes (String universidades)
{
    String[] sedes = new String[3];
    if(universidades.equalsIgnoreCase("PUCE (Cátolica)"))
    {
        sedes[0] = "Esmeraldas";
        sedes[1] = "Ibarra";
        sedes[2] = "Ambato";
    }
    
    if(universidades.equalsIgnoreCase("Universidad del Pacífico"))
    {
        sedes[0] = "Guayaquil";
        sedes[1] = "Quito";
        sedes[2] = "Cuenca";
    }
    
    if(universidades.equalsIgnoreCase("Universidad UTE"))
    {
        sedes[0] = "Quito";
        sedes[1] = "Santo Domingo";
    }
    return sedes;
}         
private void btnsalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.dispose();
}                                        

private void btnnuevoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    txtmatri.setText("");
}                                        

private void cobuniItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                        
    if(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
    {
        if(this.cobuni.getSelectedIndex()>0)
        {
            this.cobsede.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(this.getSedes(this.cobuni.getSelectedItem().toString())));
        }
    }
}                                       

private void cobsedeItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                         
     String sede = (String) cobsede.getSelectedItem();
    if (sede.equals("Esmeraldas"))
    {
        txtmatri.setText("$700");
    }
```

Comment: ¿Consideraste usar objetos? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Tu codigo ya muestra un precio al seleccionar una sede... entonces... que mas queres hacer?? el resto es seguir con la misma logica,

Comment: Concuerdo con @padaleiana, usa objetos; no es difícil y el inmenso beneficio es para tí. En su defecto usa algún [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 0):

era un programa muy sencillo, ya pude hacerlo, este fue el codigo que usé, saqué un 10.

```
private void cobsedeItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                         
     String sede = (String) cobsede.getSelectedItem();
    if (sede.equals("Esmeraldas"))
    {
        txtmatri.setText("$700");
    }
    if (sede.equals("Ibarra"))
    {
        txtmatri.setText("$750");
    }
    if (sede.equals("Ambato"))
    {
        txtmatri.setText("$780");
    }
    
    if (sede.equals("Guayaquil"))
    {
        txtmatri.setText("$600");
    }
    if (sede.equals("Quito"))
    {
        txtmatri.setText("$635");
    }
    if (sede.equals("Cuenca"))
    {
        txtmatri.setText("$649");
    }
    
    if (sede.equals("Quiito"))
    {
        txtmatri.setText("$560");
    }
    if (sede.equals("Santo Domingo"))
    {
        txtmatri.setText("$490");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Leila, me alegra que hayas podido resolverlo, pero no elimines la pregunta, ya que no solo puedes ayudar a otros que tengan problemas similares, sino que puede que te "regalen" algunos puntitos de reputación...

Comment: Leila, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a implementar tu código con objetos, de esta forma, no solo es más claro, sino que es fácil de mantener y actualizar.

```
public class Sede {

   String nombre;  
   double valorMatricula;

   public Sede( double matricula, String nom ) { 
      valorMatricula = matricula;
      nombre = nom;
   }  
   
   public double getValorMatricula() {
      return valorMatricula;
   }
   
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return nombre;
   }
}
```

Como verás, la clase **Sede**, no necesita de comentarios, tiene sus dos atributos, un método que devuelve el importe de la matrícula, y sobre-escribimos el método **toString()**, para que sea lo que se muestra en el **JComboBox**.

```
public class Universidad {

   Sede sedes[]; 
   String nombre;

   public Universidad( String nomb, Sede sedess[] ) {
      sedes = sedess;
      nombre = nomb; 
   }

   public String toString() {
      return nombre;
   }

   public Sede[] getSedes() {
      return sedes;
   }

}
```

Esta clase tampoco es la gran cosa, tiene un array que contiene los objetos **Sede**, y su propio nombre, al igual que la anterior, sobre-escribimos **toString()**.

```
public class Universidades {

   Universidad universidades[]; 
   Gui gui;

   public Universidades() {
      String unis[] = {
         "PUCE (Cátolica)", "Universidad del Pacífico", "Universidad UTE"
      };
      String sedess[][] = {
         { "Esmeraldas", "Ibarra", "Ambato" },
         { "Guayaquil", "Quito", "Cuenca" },
         { "Quito", "Santo Domingo" }
      };
      double matriculas[][] = {
         { 1000, 900, 800 },
         { 700, 600, 500 },
         { 400, 300 }
      };
      universidades = new Universidad[ unis.length ];
      for( int i = 0; i < unis.length; i++ ) {
         Sede sedes[] = new Sede[ sedess[ i ].length ];
         for( int j = 0; j < sedess[ i ].length; j++ ) {
            sedes[ j ] = new Sede( matriculas[ i ][ j ], sedess[ i ][ j ] );
         }
         universidades[ i ] = new Universidad( unis[ i ], sedes );
      }
      gui = new Gui(); 
      gui.setUnis( universidades );
      gui.setSedes( universidades[ 0 ].getSedes() );
   }

   public Universidad[] getUniversidades() {
       return universidades;
   }
}
```

Esta clase se encarga de instanciar las universidades y sus sedes, primero crea el array que contendrá las universidades, luego crea (dentro del for) un array que contendrá las sedes de la universidad que esta en la posición del array que recorremos, inicializa cada sede, tomando los datos de sus respectivos array's, y por último, instancia el objeto **Universidad**.
Terminado el proceso, se crea la interfaz de usuario (eso depende de como manejes tu el programa) y setea los respectivos **JComboBox**.

```
public void setSedes( Sede[] sedes ) {
   cobsede.setBounds( 300, 100, 200, 30 );
   panel.add( cobsede );
   cobsede.repaint();
   DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel( sedes );
   cobsede.setModel( model );
   cobsede.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
         aa.cobsedeItemStateChanged( e );
      }
   } );
}

public void setUnis( Universidad universidades[] ) {
   cobuni = new JComboBox( universidades );
   cobuni.setBounds( 100, 100, 200, 30 );
   panel.add( cobuni );
   cobuni.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
         aa.cobuniItemStateChanged( e );
      }
   } );
}

private void cobuniItemStateChanged( java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt ) {
   setSedes( ( (Universidad) cobuni.getSelectedItem() ).getSedes() );
}

private void cobsedeItemStateChanged( java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt ) {
   Sede sede = (Sede) cobsede.getSelectedItem();
   txtmatri.setText( String.valueOf( sede.getValorMatricula() ) );
}
```

por último quedan los método de tu interfaz gráfica, como verás, a los **JComboBox** en vez de pasarles array de **String**, directamente le pasamos el array de universidades y el de sedes, para que el "combo" te muestre el nombre (sino, no muestra nada) es que sobre-escribimos el método **toString()**, de **Universidad** y de **Sede**, los que devuelvan esos métods, será lo que se muestre.
Cualquier duda que te genere este código, pregunta que estamos para ayudar.